# How to set ToolManager Readonly mode using ToolManagerBuilder in XamarinForms Pdftron

Tags: pdftron

Am using Pdftron Xamarin Forms for our Android Application for viewing and annotating pdf documents. How to set ToolManager.ReadOnly property by using ToolManagerBuilder class?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a document as readOnly you will have to set the DocumentEditingEnabled(false) property in the ViewerConfig.Builder.
Please see here for more information : [DocumentEditingEnabled](https://www.pdftron.com/api/xamarinandroid/tools/api/pdftron.PDF.Config.ViewerConfig.Builder.html#pdftron_PDF_Config_ViewerConfig_Builder_DocumentEditingEnabled_System_Boolean_)

Comment: Do you know how to listen to annotationchanged event in xamarin forms?

I think I have to implement IAnnotationModificationListener. But am not sure how to attach it using ToolManagerBuilder.

Am using pdftron.PDF.Controls.DocumentView2 as given in this sample
https://github.com/PDFTron/xamarin-forms-sample

Comment: Hey @BalajiGunasekaran this is a link to a demo with an example for setting the listener to the ToolManager :  https://github.com/PDFTron/xamarin-forms-sample/compare/demo-annot-sync